# MS word macro to find words between square brackets [ ] and add them to table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS WORD document where you find words between square brackets [  ]
For example: [ECU_Configured] [HV_READY] [Signal_Faulted].  Each word between brackets I call it a DEFINITION.  Many people work on this document and adds new DEFINITIONS every now and then.  A table at the end of document shall contain all the DEFINITIONS and doing this manually is cumbersome and prone to error.

I am trying to write a VBA macro which will scan the entire WORD document and finds every DEFINITION, then, it shall take the found DEFINITION and,as long as the DEFINITION is not found in the first column of such table, it should be added it in a new row to the table. (actually this row shall contain 2 columns.  The DEFINITION shall be placed in the first column of this newly added row)

If the DEFINITION is already found in the first column, then do nothing and proceed to check if the next DEFINITION found is already in the first column or not.

I really appreciate any tips or suggestions.  The part of checking if the DEFINITION is already found or not in the first column of the table is what I find the hardest to figure it out. THANKS!

Comment: show the code you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a C function that did exactly what you are describing using the Execute method of the Find object. The pertinent code is:

```
HRESULT hr = Range_get_Find(pRange, &pFind);    
VARIANT varText, varMWC;

varText.vt = VT_BSTR;
varText.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"(\\[{2})(*)(\\]{2})");
varMWC.vt = VT_BOOL; 
varMWC.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;

hr = AutowrapNamedInvoke(&varResult, pFind, L"Execute", 2,
    L"FindText", &varText, L"MatchWildcards", &varMWC);

while( SUCCEEDED(hr) && varResult.boolVal == VARIANT_TRUE) {

    BSTR        bstrTag;
    hr = Range_get_Text(pRange, &bstrTag);

    // Process your text

    hr = AutowrapNamedInvoke(&varResult, pFind, L"Execute", 2,
        L"FindText", &varText, L"MatchWildcards", &varMWC);

}
```

You get the initial Range object from the Document object. The AutowrapNamedInvoke is a helper function for calling Dispath methods with named arguments. The gist is though the Execute method is being called on the Find object with named parameters FindText = "\[{2})(*)(\]{2})" and MatchWildCards = True.

"(\[{2})(*)(\]{2})" is a regular expression which matches [[any text]]. I used two braces. Instead of one. You can find out more about Word regular expressions here: [Word reg exp](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

The following is a translation into VBA:

```
Sub FindTags()

    Dim myRange
    Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content

    Dim myFind
    Set myFind = myRange.Find

    While (myFind.Execute(FindText:="(\[{2})(*)(\]{2})", MatchWildcards:=True))

        'Process your tag here
        MsgBox (myRange.Text)

    Wend

End Sub
```

Note you can match [any text] by changing the regular expression to "([)(*)(])". Also in the c strings there are double \ because of the escape character.

Edited: Alright, I figured the searching was the harder part. Assuming your reference table is the LAST table in your document, the following should do the trick:

```
Sub FindTags()

    Dim myRange
    Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content

    Dim myFind
    Set myFind = myRange.Find

    While (myFind.Execute(FindText:="(\[{2})(*)(\]{2})", MatchWildcards:=True))

        ProcessTag myRange.Text

    Wend

End Sub

Sub ProcessTag(tagtext As String)

    Dim i
    i = Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

    Dim saveTable As Table
    Set saveTable = Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(i)

    If (DoesTagExist(saveTable, tagtext) = False) Then

        AddTag saveTable, tagtext

    End If

End Sub

Function DoesTagExist(ByRef t As Table, tagtext As String) As Boolean

    Dim ret As Boolean
    ret = False

    Dim r As Row
    For Each r In t.Rows

        Dim rowtext As String
        rowtext = Left(r.Cells.Item(1).Range.Text, Len(tagtext))

        If (rowtext = tagtext) Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    DoesTagExist = ret
End Function

Sub AddTag(ByRef t As Table, tagtext As String)

    Dim r As Row
    Set r = t.Rows.Add

    r.Cells.Item(1).Range.Text = tagtext

End Sub
```

Comment: cburn11,I do appreciate your help and info provided.  The code you show finds all the [words] between brackets.  Do you have a suggestion about the second part of the macro?.  Every [word] found shall be checked to see if exist already in the first column of a table, if it does, then do nothing, else, add a new row to the table (1 row x 2 columns) and paste the [word] in the first column.  Then loop for the other [words] found.  Thanks